# Can't add assemble reference to project

Tags: c#, .net, reference, .net-assembly

I have a web site on Framework 4.5.1.
When I compile I have a missing assembly reference error for System.Data.DataExtensions.

So I go to add a reference tick the box close the dialog , recompile.  Same assembly is missing again.  Go back to references and the assembly is no longer ticked.  It does add it the the web.config but the reference always disappears.

I came across this link [similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a46a0bc-550c-4cba-9f1e-9f73b1600e02/systemdatadatasetextension-reference-problem-in-net-40?forum=adodotnetdataset)
but the solution was only having using System.Data instead of using System.Data.DataExtensions.  But my using statement are already only System.Data.

Can anyone assist ?

Comment: Can you simply add the assembly to your csproj file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that when the project was migrated to 4.5.1 framework the web config file wasn't update and still contains a reference to the 3.0 framework.
That is what was is preventing the assembly reference being added.

Upgrading the framework seems not to update the web config with the changes.